# Building Web Parts inside MS Exchange

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server, web-parts, outlook-web-app

I'm a SharePoint Developer and I have a new opportunity and my mission is to build a webpart / webservice around OWA (Outlook Web App) and MS Exchange.
I don't have experience using MS Exchange and OWA.
I searched everywhere in google and I only get results about Sharepoint Web Parts. I want to know if that exists, MS Exchange webparts or they mean Sharepoint Web Parts Using Owa and Exchange?

I need help please if anyone can help with an answer or some links. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as Exchange Webparts from Exchange 2013 up the way of doing extensibility in the OWA and Outlook clients is to use Addin's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/ . The feature set has grown over the years so depending on what version of Exchange server you have (or if you using Office 365) will determine the features that are available to you.